# Typescript generates a 'property does not exist on type' error (code converted from JS)

Tags: typescript

I have a for loop that Typescript is complaining about with a `Property does not exist on type` error message.

The code is:

```
  for (category of this.theImageCategories) {
    if (category.checked) {
      categoryCount++;
      selectedCategories.push(category.id);
    }
  }
```

Typescript is complaining `Property checked does not exist on type '{}'`

What do I have to do to get rid of this error message?

Comment: How is declared the variable `category`?

Comment: The variable is not declared (the code is Javascript and is being moved to Transcript).

Comment: The issue is not related to the loop. The variable `category` has the type `{}`, that's why you cannot call a member `checked`. See for example [this code in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20category%20%3D%20{}%0Acategory.checked).

Comment: I have previously tried: var category = {
        checked: false,
        id: 0
      }; 
But this produces the error message "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'category' must be of type '{}', but here has type '{ checked: boolean; id: number; }'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115396/discussion-between-paleo-and-bill-noble).

Comment: @Paleo Consider making an answer so that this question might be properly resolved and wrapped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to the loop. The variable `category` has the type `{}`, that's why you cannot call a member `checked`. For example, the following code produces the same error:

```
let category = {}
category.checked // Error: Property 'checked' does not exist on type '{}'
```

> I have been moving some Javascript code over to Typescript because it is now a requirement of the framework I am using so I am picking up all kinds of inconsistencies *[quoted from the chat]*

The variable `category` has been declared elsewhere in the program. In order to find it, I suggest to use `let` instead of `var`. In this second example, the second declaration makes the compiler complain on the two variables:

```
var category = {} // Error: Duplicate identifier 'category'
// ...
let category = { checked: false, id: 0 } // Error: Duplicate identifier 'category'
```